# Username displaying as domain\sid rather than Friendly name in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have a Sp 2016 environment. There are more than 5400 users synced in the environment from AD. However for some users the Account name is displaying as domain\sid e.g domain\RD504334 rather than domain\name.

Has anyone had this issue before?

[image]

Comment: check if the synchronization is without any errors.

Comment: it completed without errors.

Comment: to this is probably cause of this, if account has problem to sync, there is seen only the login, not others attributes. You mus resolve it. Which synchronization do you use? ActiveDirectory Import or have you installed FIM?

Comment: that is the funny thing, everything for those users is synced perfectly. All the attributes have been imported. The account name property displays as e.g. domain\z0993gal. if I use this to check permissions for the users, it displays the first name and last name of the user correctly.

Comment: AD Import to answer your earlier question.

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška i added an image to show you

Comment: this has no info. look at import logs, whats the problem? and again AD import or FIM? you can find it in UPS under Synchronization settings

Comment: there is a timer job involved that copies the preferred name and other attributes to the site collections where users have signed in to. can you check if the timer job "User Profile service application proxy - User Profile to SharePoint quick synchronization" and "User Profile service application proxy - User Profile to SharePoint full synchronization" ran successfully?